# Как тернарный оператор  перевести в обычному синтаксису

Tags: php

Что-то я тут совсем не догоняю, как эту строку

```
<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=<?=$exif['GPS']['GPSLatitudeRef'] == 'S' ? '-' : '' ?><?=$latitude['degrees']?>+<?=$latitude['minutes']?>'+<?=$latitude['seconds']?>'',+<?=$exif['GPS']['GPSLongitudeRef'] == 'W' ? '-' : '' ?><?=$longitude['degrees']?>+<?=$longitude['minutes']?>'+<?=$longitude['seconds']?>''" target="_blank">
```

загнать в переменную, не могу разобраться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@eicto](/users/11304/eicto)](/users/11304/eicto), почему не тернарный?

Вполне себе тернарный -

```
<?=$exif['GPS']['GPSLongitudeRef'] == 'W' ? '-' : '' ?>
```

а переписать легко

```
if($exif['GPS']['GPSLongitudeRef'] == 'W') {
    return '-';
} else {
    return ''; // для наглядности, можно было и не писать
}
```

Только вот избавляться от него я бы не советовал. Он делает код компактнее.

Поясните лучше что вы хотите сделать? Как именно загнать в переменную? Как ее потом использовать?

Comment: @ICE не заметил :) слишком безумное нагромождение, ну от этого мои рекомендации хуже не становятся.

Comment: только не return а echo вроде. хотя когда <?= ... не знаю никогда так не писал :)

Comment: при загрузке фото извлекаются exif данные с координатами GPS,и ссылка заносится в базу данных для дальнейшего использования, нужно чтобы ссылка не выводилась, а присваивалась переменной.

Comment: Не знаю правильно или нет, но я сделал так:

if(!empty($exif['GPS']['GPSLatitudeRef']) and !empty($exif['GPS']['GPSLongitudeRef'])){
$position = $latitude['degrees'].'+'.$latitude['minutes'].'+'.$latitude['seconds']."'',+".$longitude['degrees'].'+'.$longitude['minutes'].'+'.$longitude['seconds']."''";
echo '<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q='.$position.'">Посмотреть на карте</a>';

Answer (score 1):

Это в основном не тернарный оператор, это шаблон php, через [ob](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-get-clean.php) сделайте если очень надо. ну или просто

правильно расставить и экранировать кавычки и переменные (синтаксис типа `$var="string=\"substring='{$array['key']}'\"";` )

---

для справки - тернарный это когда так:

вместо

```
if ($var==="test") $var2="ok";else $var="nope";
```

пишем

```
$var2=$var==="test"?"ok":"nope";
```